# Configuration steps for Emacs Python / IDE

Tags: python, ide

I'm newbie.
Which is the best configuration for develop in Python using Emacs?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome @hawky. Have you tried to Google an answer?

Comment: Questions about the *best* anything are typically not good questions for this site. They are generally too broad or primarily opinion-based, and so off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look using `Ecosia` yield this [awesome post](https://realpython.com/blog/python/emacs-the-best-python-editor/). Hope you find it useful!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the package elpy and read the help page of the author:
https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy and https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html